# Why is htop only available in EPEL on CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: centos, redhat, epel, htop

I'm just honestly curious why htop isn't available in the base, extras or even centosplus repos. To me it seems innocent and useful, but maybe I've overlooked some aspect of it, such as licensing, and I'm just wondering what the decisionmaking was.

Could anyone clear this up? I'm just curious and hoping to figure out what the reason was, perhaps it could give more insight into the package itself as well because I use it a lot and maybe I've overlooked something about it.

Comment: Remember that everything in the RHEL repos are packages which Red Hat has committed to support for the 10 year life of the distro (or the life of the AppStream for RHEL 8, which varies). EPEL exists because this is a small set of packages, and most people need many other things which could not possibly be included because Red Hat just doesn't have the manpower to do it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yea that makes sense, I know that CentOS is just an 'opensource version' of redhat, but I thought htop was simple enough to maintain, maybe it required use of some unstable kernel APIs though, I'd have to dig deeper for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS is RHEL repackaged without the Red Hat branding so the root of that omission lies there.

Hidden behind the Red Hat subscriber content paywall

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3159101

> Previously, a Request for Feature Enhancement was filed with Red Hat Development Engineering requesting this (htop) to be included. However, this was declined in favor of the Performance Co-Pilot toolkit. It is notable that an associated request is being evaluated for future inclusion which would pursue the pcp htop interface https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1716242

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I was hoping for, although taking a look at pcp now (the tool, not the drug), but it seems like it's very different from htop, and requires a service to be running in background, maybe I'm looking at the wrong part of it though because it seems extensive. Thanks for that answer!